# How to use multi-threading to play/pause BG Music in tkinter app?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

A part of what I am doing, needs me to have `background music` in a `tkinter` game I created long time ago. I am using `playsound.playsound`{ [Docs Here](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) } to play music . I could use any other tool if needed to achieve what I intend like `pyglet.media` or `pygame.mixer`.
As the actual program was about 1k lines, I have tried adding an [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) below.

## Desired behavior & issue

The BGM (Background Music) should start when the app is launched - of course alongside a GUI, I would have a `button` to stop the BGM OR more preferably pause/play - I do think I need to use anything other than `playsound.playsound` for pause/play behavior.

**The issue::** I can't seem to figure out how to make that `communication` between both the `threads`  so that I can stop the music from playing or perhaps `terminate` the thread playing BGM - I could create a new thread when needed.

## What I Have Tried

First up, I created two classes for GUI and BGM, each `inheriting` from `threading.Thread` - overridden the `constructor` and `run()` methods to do what I intend. Like this -

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from playsound import playsound

class BGM(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, stopSignal):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopSignal = stopSignal

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopSignal:
            playsound('LoL.mp3') # to make this function play asynchronously, pass in False as second arg.

class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        
    def run(self):
        tk.Button(self.root, text='stop').pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    guiThread = GUI()
    guiThread.start()
    musicThread = BGM(0)
    musicThread.start()
    guiThread.root.mainloop()
```

But as you can see, it will just continue to play the song infinitely as long as the app is alive. There is no communication ( or active sync ) between GUI ( the button to stop song ) and BGM thread.

Now I tried using `threading.Event()` objects. The [official docs on threading.Event()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) quotes:

> This is one of the simplest mechanisms for communication between
> threads: one thread signals an event and other threads wait for it.
>
> An event object manages an internal flag that can be set to true with
> the set() method and reset to false with the clear() method. The
> wait() method blocks until the flag is true.

I'm not sure if this is useful for me to achieve what I intend but using `threading.Event()` did not do anything for me (or maybe I wasn't able to make use of it properly)

## Now

What would you suggest to do to implement a BGM thread which can be stopped ( or paused/played preferably ) with a button(s) in the GUI thread.

Thank You For Any help Or Suggestions :)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782229/13629335 ?

Comment: Complete example with vlc is here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=HEAD

Comment: And maybe you are intrested in a behavior to pause your music if all of the app is minimized. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62638011/13629335

Comment: One way is to have two buttons, start and stop and a queue. The start button adds a "start" string to the queue and the stop button adds a "stop" string to the queue. The  BGM thread simply is in a loop doing blocking waits for the next input message on the input queue and responds accordingly. You can add a third button, "terminate", to end the program (it adds a "terminate" message to the queue before returning).

Comment: @Atlas435  Appreciate your response. That is good info on pause/play behavior normally, but I need to implement a communication between two threads which will be initiated on button press. So the question actually is- how to stop a thread from playing BGM when a button is pressed on GUI thread?

Comment: @Booboo That sounds interesting. I 'ma try to implement that & let ya know the outcome.